# Twitter feed only load periodically

Tags: jquery, twitter

I've tried many jQuery twitter feed plugins and they all seem to suffer from the same problem. Nothing loads for unless I refresh several times and then it will load once. I then need to refresh several more times before it loads again.

Is there some sort of limitation on Twitters side or does this only happen to me?

[Example](http://test3.001.co.za/stor-age/web/Blog/) - This is the test site but it is basically ready to go live except for this issue.

Comment: It loads perfect here. Since the feed loads client-side you probably have a bad connection with Twitter. Did you try on other computers on different connections?

Comment: You could get the feed in the back-end where you could cache it, and then update it client-side. So if client-side fails, the latest cache from the server could be displayed there.

Comment: This approach is recommended in the link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter rate limits the number of calls you can make per hour perhaps this is why you are seeing this problem

see [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting)

Comment: Thanks for the link. When looking at my rate limit status I had no hits left. I haven't used it that much but I suppose I'll just have to wait
<hash>
  <remaining-hits type="integer">0</remaining-hits>
  <hourly-limit type="integer">150</hourly-limit>
  <reset-time-in-seconds type="integer">1275481646</reset-time-in-seconds>
  <reset-time type="datetime">2010-06-02T12:27:26+00:00</reset-time>
</hash>